# jQuery change button color onclick

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, dotnetnuke

I have multiple buttons that I use when people answer a question. How would I get the buttons to change colors when a person clicks on the button? I do not know jQuery, I have been told that it is the best thing to use for this.

Here is the code I have for the HTML part:

```
<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="line-height: 18px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 24px;">In the past three months, how often have you used marijuana?<br />
<p><input type="submit" value=" Never " name="btnsubmit" id="answer" style="width: 200px;" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value=" Once or Twice " name="btnsubmit" id="answer" style="width: 200px;" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value=" Monthly " name="btnsubmit" id="answer" style="width: 200px;" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value=" Daily or Almost Daily " name="btnsubmit" id="answer" style="width: 200px;" /></p>
</span></div>
<div>
<p style="text-align: right;"><a onclick="window.open(this.href,'_parent');return false;" href="/mobile/Static2.aspx"><input type="submit" value=" Next " name="btnsubmit" style="width: 100px;" /></a></p>
</div>
```

I am really new at coding so any kind of help would be appreciated!

Comment: $('#answer').click( function() { $(this).css({ 'background' : '#00ff00' }); }); Please, refer jQuery documentation for more details about it's functions and API

Comment: I hope this isn't homework. And what's with all these duplicate IDs. This is 4 times in a row today. Please note that IDs are suppose to be unique.

Comment: No this is not homework. One of my jobs is updating a website and I am trying to move into a new direction with how the site functions. I am not much of a coder!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
$(this).css('color','red');
});
```

Use class, Demo:- https://jsfiddle.net/BX6Df/

```
   $('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
          $(this).addClass('red');
});
```

if you want to toggle the color each click, you can try this:- https://jsfiddle.net/SMNks/

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass('red');
});


.red
{
    background-color:red;
}
```

Updated answer for your comment.

https://jsfiddle.net/H2Xhw/

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(){
    $('input[type="submit"].red').removeClass('red')
        $(this).addClass('red');
});
```

Comment: Is there a way if they choose one then choose another the first one would go back to it's original color?

Comment: This is what I was looking for, sorry it took so long to accept it, but had to play around just a tad bit with it to get it to work within my Dnn installation!

Answer (score 5):

I would just create a separate CSS class:

```
.ButtonClicked {
    background-color:red;
}
```

And then add the class on click:

```
$('#ButtonId').on('click',function(){
    !$(this).hasClass('ButtonClicked') ? addClass('ButtonClicked') : '';
});
```

This should do what you're looking for, showing by [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edVaS/). If you're curious about the logic with the `?` and such, its called [ternary (or conditional) operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), and its just a concise way to do the simple if logic to check if the class has already been added.

You can also create the ability to have an "on/off" switch feel by toggling the class:

```
$('#ButtonId').on('click',function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('ButtonClicked');
});
```

Shown by [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edVaS/1/). Just food for thought.

Comment: this is exactly why i deleted my original comment, because it was inevitably going to lead to a bickerfest. didnt expect it to be this passive aggressive, but nonetheless i wanted to avoid it. ive updated my answer, lets just shake hands and call it square.

Answer (score 3):

Use CSS:

```
<style>
input[name=btnsubmit]:active {
color: green;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this code to your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("input[type='submit']").click(function(){
      $(this).css('background-color','red');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: When using this, how would I make the button stay read? After clicking it then moving off of it, it changes back to the original color

Comment: A javascript only runs on the site where it is included. If you want to save information you need to store it somewhere. Like a cookie for example.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include the jquery framework in your document head from a cdn for example:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Then you have to include a own script for example:

```
(function( $ ) {

  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('input').click(function() {
          $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
      }
  });


  $(window).load(function() { 
  });

})( jQuery );
```

This part is a mapping of the $ to jQuery, so actually it is jQuery('selector').function();

```
(function( $ ) {

})( jQuery );
```

Here you can find die api of jquery where all functions are listed with examples and explanation: http://api.jquery.com/

Answer (score 0):

Using jquery, try this. if your button id is say id= clickme

$("clickme").on('çlick', function(){

$(this).css('background-color', 'grey'); .......

Comment: The same way has been shown be most of the other answers already.